# PHP - Generate images and free memory

Tags: php, image, memory

This script takes images from a folder, resize, apply a watermark and save the new images to another folder.

The script works but crashed near the end if the images are more than 21.

The *readdir* function read correctly all the files in the folder .

Is this a memory problem?

```
<?php
$gallery = $_GET['gallery'];
$directory = "input/$gallery/"; //Imposto la directory da leggere
mkdir("output/$gallery", 0700); //Creo la directory di output
$watermark_l = "source/watermark_l.png";
$watermark_l = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_l);
$x_watermark_l = imagesx($watermark_l);
$y_watermark_l = imagesy($watermark_l);
$watermark_s = "source/watermark_s.png";
$watermark_s = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_s);
$x_watermark_s = imagesx($watermark_s);
$y_watermark_s = imagesy($watermark_s);
if (is_dir($directory)) //Apriamo una directory e leggiamone il contenuto
{
    if ($directory_handle = opendir($directory)) //Apro l'oggetto directory
    {
        while (($file = readdir($directory_handle)) != false) //Scorro l'oggetto fino a quando non è termnato cioè false
        {
            if ( ($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "Thumbs.db") && ($file != "cover.jpg") && ($file != "Cover.jpg") && ($file != ".DS_Store") )
            {
                $filename = "input/$gallery/$file"; //Imposto il path dell'immagine
                echo "<strong>" . $file . "</strong></br>";
                //Imposto le nuove dimensioni
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
                if ( $width > $height ) //Immagine con orientamento orizzontale
                {
                    //LARGE 3000x2000 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    $x_large = 3000;
                    $y_large = 2000;
                    //Ridimensiono l'immagine
                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($x_large, $y_large);
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x_large, $y_large, $width, $height);
                    //Watermark per immagini formato large
                    imagecopy($image_p, $watermark_l, 15, 15, 0, 0, $x_watermark_l, $y_watermark_l);
                    //Salvo l'immagine modificata
                    imagejpeg($image_p, "output/$gallery/3000x2000_$file", 100);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    imagedestroy($image_p);
                    echo $filename . " ridimensionata 3000x2000 e salvata</br>";
                    //SMALL 500x330  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    $x_large = 500;
                    $y_large = 330;
                    //Ridimensiono l'immagine
                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($x_large, $y_large);
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x_large, $y_large, $width, $height);
                    //Watermark per immagini formato small
                    imagecopy($image_p, $watermark_s, 5, 5, 0, 0, $x_watermark_s, $y_watermark_s);
                    //Salvo l'immagine modificata
                    imagejpeg($image_p, "output/$gallery/500x330_$file", 100);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    imagedestroy($image_p);
                    echo $filename . " ridimensionata 500x330 e salvata</br>";
                }
                else
                {
                    //LARGE 3000x2000 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    $x_large = 2000;
                    $y_large = 3000;
                    //Ridimensiono l'immagine
                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($x_large, $y_large);
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x_large, $y_large, $width, $height);
                    //Watermark per immagini formato large
                    imagecopy($image_p, $watermark_l, 15, 15, 0, 0, $x_watermark_l, $y_watermark_l);
                    //Salvo l'immagine modificata
                    imagejpeg($image_p, "output/$gallery/3000x2000_$file", 100);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    imagedestroy($image_p);
                    echo $filename . " ridimensionata 2000x3000 e salvata</br>";
                    //SMALL 500x330  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    $x_large = 330;
                    $y_large = 500;
                    //Ridimensiono l'immagine
                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($x_large, $y_large);
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x_large, $y_large, $width, $height);
                    //Watermark per immagini formato small
                    imagecopy($image_p, $watermark_s, 5, 5, 0, 0, $x_watermark_s, $y_watermark_s);
                    //Salvo l'immagine modificata
                    imagejpeg($image_p, "output/$gallery/500x330_$file", 100);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    imagedestroy($image_p);
                    echo $filename . " ridimensionata 330x500 e salvata</br>";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($directory_handle); //Chiudo la lettura della directory
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: More than 21 what? What error are you getting? Is there anything in your error log?

Comment: chances are that your script is timing out use `set_time_limit(0);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php